# Calling promise resolve multiple times, returning same old results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

In my angular project, I have two separate components.

**parent.component.ts**

```
mypromise = this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost').toPromise()
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-children #child [promise]="mypromise"></app-children>

<button (click)="child.update()">Update now!</button>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input promise: Promise<any>

ngOnInit(){
  this.getMyPromise()

  //results:
  //[{id: 1, text: 'abc'}, {id: 2, text: 'abcd'}]  
}

update(){
  this.getMyPromise()
  //expected:
  //[{id: 1, text: 'abc'}, {id: 2, text: 'abcd'}, {id: 3, text: 'new data'}]  

  //results:
  //[{id: 1, text: 'abc'}, {id: 2, text: 'abcd'}]
  //same outdated results of first call
}

getMyPromise(){
 this.promise
 .then(data=>console.log(data)) //here i log my results in console
 .catch(e=>console.log(e))
}
```

When my component start, the promise is resolved normally with my content, but if I call my promise again using the `update` function in `Update now!` button, after my data in backend has updated, the promise return same results of first call in `ngOnInit()`

How can I call the updated data in my backend using this same promise? That is possible?

Comment: in general terms `yes` you can resolve a resolved promise, but in this I case I don't think as you are converting an `Observable` to `Promise` but Hang on I'll try it out

Comment: No, you can't resolve a resolved promise. Doing so won't throw exceptions, but it will also not have any observable effect.

Answer (score 0):

A promise is a one-way state machine so once it is resolved, it will stay that way forever.  You cannot change that.  Only when it is in the `pending` state can you resolve it with a value.  Trying to call `resolve()` again on a promise that is not in the `pending` state just ignores the call (does nothing).

> How can i call the updated data in my backend using this same promise? That is possible?

You will need to call your original asynchronous operation again:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost').toPromise()
```

to get a new promise that is tied to the new asynchronous action to get the new data.  This new promise will resolve with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

You always get the same result because you don't call de server again.

For your code work as you expect you need to implement more lines of code  like that:

**parent.component.ts**

```
public mypromise;
    ngOnInit() {
     mypromise = this.getSomethig();
    }

    public function getSomething() {
     return this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost').toPromise();
    }
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() promise: Promise<any>
@Output() getSomething = new EventEmitter<any>();

ngOnInit(){
 this.promise
 .then(data=>console.log(data)) //here i log my results in console
 .catch(e=>console.log(e))

 //results:
 //[{id: 1, text: 'abc'}, {id: 2, text: 'abcd'}]  
}

update(){
     this.getSomething.emit();
}
```

See more about event emitter in https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular